# Почему здесь нужно ставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

1. Петя, после полученного им решительного отказа, ушел в свою комнату и там, заперевшись от всех, горько плакал. Почему "после полученного им решительного отказа" здесь выделяется запятыми?
2. Для гусар же Павлоградского полка весь этот отступательный поход, в лучшую пору лета, с достаточным продовольствием, был самым простым и веселым делом. Почему в этом предложении "в лучшую пору лета, с достаточным продовольствием" выделены запятыми?

Answer (score 1):

Обособление обстоятельственных оборотов, выраженных падежными формами существительных, является факультативным. В данном случае обособлены распространенные обороты с целью их смыслового выделения.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114

1) *Петя, **после полученного им решительного отказа**, ушел в свою комнату и там, заперевшись от всех, горько плакал.*

Актуализация (смысловое выделение) обстоятельственного оборота со значением причины.

2) *Для гусар же Павлоградского полка весь этот отступательный поход, **в лучшую пору лета, с достаточным продовольствием,** был самым простым и веселым делом.*

Обособление однородных несогласованных определений (также актуализация со значением причины): поход был веселым делом, так как погода стояла хорошая, а продовольствия было достаточно.